# How to give out ERC20 tokens w/o receiving eth?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tokens

Is there a way to give out ERC20 tokens indiscriminately under a certain condition, but not by receiving eth? i.e without using the fallback function?

Answer (score 1):

Ether is not tied to tokens in any way. The only part where you *have to* have Ether is to pay for the transaction costs.

You can distribute your tokens based on whatever criteria you wish. Some hand them out in so-called airdrops, where they are given out half-randomly to different places without asking if the receiver wants them or not.